zoomsdk integration: camera first time view minibug
I'm integrating zoomsdk into my project, everything is OK
But when I click the camera icon to turn it on, I get a black screen until I resize the zoom window - then the image starts to transfer, how to solve this problem? because this is a built-in zoom frame, I can’t influence it with my code
Moreover, this problem is only the first time the camera is connected; the next time you turn it on/off, everything works correctly
I'll provide the code if necessary, it's just completely standard for this task
I would be grateful for any help
